# Fluent Nhibernate he parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-routing

project, I get an error the problem is;

**"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'Void Delete(Int32)' in 'BlogNewCMS.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parametre adı: parameters"**

Controller;

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Delete(int Id)  
    {

        using (var session = FluentNHibernateConnectingAdmin.OpenSession())
        {

            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var article = session.QueryOver<Article>().Where(x => x.Id == 3).SingleOrDefault();

                session.Delete(article);

                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Page;

```
                        @foreach (var active in Model)
                    {


                        using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "home", FormMethod.Post))
                        {

                            <tr role="row" class="gradeA odd">
                                <td class="sorting_1">@active.UserID</td>
                                <td>@active.Topic</td>
                                <td>@active.TopicDetail</td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="name" value="Sil" />

                                </td>
                            </tr>

                    }
                        }
```

Routing;

```
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Delete method expects an Id parameter of `int` type. But your form does not have one ,hence not passing one when you submit the form.

Add one input field to your form with name attribute value set to  `"Id"`

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "home", FormMethod.Post))
{
     <tr role="row" class="gradeA odd">
          <td class="sorting_1">@active.UserID</td>
          <td>@active.Topic</td>
          <td>@active.TopicDetail</td>
          <td class="text-center">
               <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="name" value="Sil" /> 
               <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="@active.Id" />
          </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Also you probably want to add a return type to your delete method so that it returns a response.

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
  // to do : Delete
  return RedirectToAction("DeletedSuccessfully");
   // Assuming you have an action method called DeletedSuccessfully exist 
   // which shows the "Success message to user
}
```